# For GIT, why is it bad to make changes on the master, vs creating a branch?

Tags: git

From what I understand, when working with GIT, if I make code changes, I should create a branch to make my changes.
Why is this better (or more preferred) to just working off of the master without making a branch?

Everything is saved so you can still go back if you mess up,  you can still add comments to your commits, and anything you do at the branch gets merged anyways right?

curious just so I have a better understanding.

Comment: Most of the suggestions are about coordinating with others via a central repository. As long as you're the only author, you can be way more flexible about where you commit to. There's still a good reason to have *some* structure, but it's no longer as important.

Comment: "Should" and "better" are value judgments. That's a matter of opinion. Do what you want to do. If you think it's easier not making any branches, and you have no other reason to make branches, don't make any.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with other people, you definitely want to do this so that you don't conflict with things others are doing.  In addition, you may want to perform some sort of code review or run a CI check before merging into `master`, so that's another reason.

If you're working on a project by yourself, it's less important.  However, since I have CI set up for my projects (to make sure I don't break them), I prefer to work on a branch so that my changes can be tested before merging into `master`.  Working on a temporary project branch also means I can easily switch back to the original code if my change takes more time or requires more work than I originally anticipated.

Since branches are cheap and easy to create in Git, it's a good practice to get into if you can, but if it seems too burdensome to do for a small, single-user project, then you can just skip it.